# Access overriden parent virtual method in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

In the following code, how can I access `Base::g()` from `pBase`? (and still get "`pBase->g();`" to work as it does below)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void f(){ cout << "Base::f()" << endl; }
    virtual void g(){ cout << "Base::g()" << endl; }
    void h(){ cout << "Base::h()" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    void f(){ cout << "Derived::f()" << endl; }
    virtual void g(){ cout << "Derived::g()" << endl; }
    void h(){ cout << "Derived::h()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Base *pBase = new Derived;
    pBase->f();
    pBase->g();
    pBase->h();

    Derived *pDerived = new Derived;
    pDerived->f();
    pDerived->g();
    pDerived->h(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Derived::f()
Derived::g()
Base::h()
Derived::f()
Derived::g()
Derived::h()
```

Also, is `Derived::f()` exactly the same as `Derived::g()`? (ie. automatically defined as `virtual`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `pBase->Base::g();` to force the call of `g` in `Base`.
2. Yes, `Derived::f` is `virtual`. I personally find the re-emphasising of `virtual` to be in poor taste. Since C++11, you can use the `override` specifier on overridden functions, and then a compiler issues a diagnostic if `virtual` is dropped from the base class.

Comment: @Bathsheba So simple! Thanks!!